# What does おびび mean?

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

I don't know a lot of kanji, sorry.

I saw someone write, 初めまして、おびびです but I can't seem to figure out what obibi means. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 6):

In a phrase:

> 初めまして、〇〇です

〇〇 is expected to be a name, nickname, or some other proper noun by which that person wants to be called/associated with.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I had a dumb moment. haha. Thank you for answering, though. I need sleep. Oh, I feel stupid.